# Maven - error cannot find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, javacpp

I tried to build this example : https://github.com/oltzen/JavaCppExample with Maven (mvn clean install) on Linux.
After the successful build, when I run :  java de.oltzen.javacppexample.Abc : it says 'could not load or find the main class'

The video tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZrrqZLhtmw) uses Eclipse and it runs the program with Run as .. Java Application

Is the POM file missing something ?

I tried to add this plugin in POM but it did not work:

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>de.oltzen.javacppexample.Abc</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I am executing from JavaCppExample/target/classes/ :-

The /classes folder contains package folders : de/oltzen/javacppexample/
The last folder contains the class file Abc.class

So I run the command :
java de.oltzen.javacppexample.Abc

The /target folder contains : 
1) classes [folder containing the package] 
2) JavaCppExample.jar
3) maven-archiver
4) maven-status

Please help

Comment: Try cleaning the project couple of times in eclipse or restart the eclipse and then try again.

Comment: Are you looking to create an uber JAR?

Comment: @SamuelAudet No, just build and execute it. whether simply with main class or with Jar file

Comment: @Smile I am building the project with command line.

Comment: Please update the question with the folder in which you are running `java de.oltzen.javacppexample.Abc` and what all files are present in this folder.

Comment: @Smile I have updated the post. Kindly check.

Comment: If you are able to generate a jar file without any error, then you use "java -jar /relative_path/fileName.jar"

Comment: @YogendraR I have tried but same issue. I have executed from /target/classes/ folder

Comment: jar file should not be inside classes folder

Comment: @YogendraR No. It is not. It is in the /target folder

Comment: so run that command from target folder

Comment: @YogendraR . I ran it from target folder. java -jar <JAR> . It says no main manifest attribute, in JavaCppExample.jar

Comment: open your jar file and see if there is manifest.mf file that file should contain main class attribute then only it will work

Comment: @YogendraR there is no manifest file. However I tried to specify it in the POM file but then it said :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bytedeco/javacpp/Pointer.    My class is extending this third party JavaCPP class - Pointer

Comment: I didn't know that you are using third party libraries as well. To make it as a runnable jar, make it fat/uber jar. you can use maven-assembly-plugin, go through the maven docs

Comment: Add the dependency to pom which has `org/bytedeco/javacpp/Pointer` class

Comment: @Smile it is already added. see the POM in the github link

Answer (score 1):

I added the following plugins for maven copy dependencies and executed **java -jar javaCppExample.jar**  [from /target folder]and it worked. Thanks everyone !

[Simply build using **mvn clean install**]

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <!--  Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>de.oltzen.javacppexample.Abc</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to run your prgramm via maven then use exec-maven-plugin.

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>de.oltzen.javacppexample.Abc</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Explore more here => https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html

If you want to build & run as jar then use assembly plugin

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>${project.basedir}/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>de.oltzen.javacppexample.Abc</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

Explore more about Maven assembly plugin to customize to your needs.

Comment: First solution by Adonis worked here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470641/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-maven-project-out-of-eclipse